# How can I make the jQuery Mask Plugin display prices with a period instead of a comma?

Tags: javascript, input

I'm using the [jQuery Mask Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) library for inputs containing prices. This library is adding a comma in the input price format, but I need a dot for the price. I can't find where this functionality is in the library.

**Example**: If you write "**1990**" it's masking as "**19,90**" (with a comma).
But I want "**1990**" -> "**19.90**" (with a dot).

The library I am using is here: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.0/jquery.mask.js

Comment: Did you ready the [documentation](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html)? This looks like you should be able to do what you want through the API.

Comment: I was going to do it, but I waited 2 minutes for the answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this. Check out the recursive digits section [in the docs](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html).

You just need to replace the `,` with a `.`

```js
$('.currency').mask("#,##0.00", {
  reverse: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.13.4/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input class="currency" type="text" value="1990">
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much. its working. But it's save "19.90" -> "1990.00" in database :/

Comment: @LiptoNiceTea How are you sending it to the database?

Comment: I checked and found the problem. It's completely solved. Thank you again for the help. :)